# Dump GHashTable to file

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

In my application, I need to save a [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) GHashTable instance into disk, and then load into memory later. But I cannot find any way to dump the instance directly.

An option is not to save the GHashTable directly, but save the entries one after another. When loading, load the entries one by one, and insert to a new hash table. But I find that it takes much time to perform this operation:

```
g_hash_table_insert(hash, (gpointer) (mer_v), (gpointer) m);
```

It takes around 20 minutes to load 60 million entries. If I simply load the entries but not perform the insertion, it takes only 10 seconds.

So is there any alternative way to save the GHashTable efficiently? Thanks

======================

Update:

My hashtable key is uint64_t. This code runs for around 10 seconds:

```
for (i = 0; i < 60000000; i++) {
    tmp = (uint64_t*) malloc (sizeof(uint64_t));
    *tmp = i;
    g_hash_table_insert(hash, (gpointer) (tmp), (gpointer) tmp);
}
```

But this code runs for more than 10 minutes:

```
for (i = 0; i < meta->n_kmers; i++) {
    m = g_ptr_array_index(kmer_list, i);
    tmp = (uint64_t*) malloc (sizeof(uint64_t));
    *tmp = m->s;
    g_hash_table_insert(hash, (gpointer) (tmp), (gpointer) tmp);
}
```

Majority of my entry keys `m->s` are with ~60 bits.

Comment: I think that your use-case is a bit over the "comfortable" design size of the GHashTable ... It doesn't even provide a sized constructor, which would be handy to cut down on the number of re-allocations it's sure to be doing in your case.

Comment: @unwind Is there any alternative libraries/codes with higher efficiency? I prefer not to write it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHashTable isn't optimised for that size of a data set. You'd be better off writing your own hash table that is.

Comment: I tried c++ `std:unordered_map`, it takes around 40 seconds to load the whole data structure. Good.

Answer (score 3):

you should probably look at the gvdb code that is currently private to GIO and dconf. gvdb is an hash table optimized for reading via mmap():

https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio/gvdb/

it uses GVariant to store data in a memory efficient binary representation. the code is under LGPL v2.1+, so it can only be cut and pasted inside projects with compatible licenses.

Comment: In gvdb-builder.h, I find: `GHashTable * gvdb_hash_table_new(GHashTable *parent, const gchar *key)`. So I need to have a GHashTable first? I do not quite understand how to use it. Is there any documentation? My hash table has uint64_t keys and pointer values. Thanks.

Comment: gvdb uses string keys to address an hash table of string keys and variant values. if you're storing 64 bit integers and random pointer values then you can either wrap them into a format that is what the gvdb code expects (i.e. strings and variants) or you will have to write your own data type.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ebassi (and iain, and unwind) that GHashTable probably isn't a good fit for your use case.

[SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) should work okay, but there are also lots of extremely fast embedded key-value stores available.  The [Wikipedia page for dbm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm) lists lots of them.  If I were you I would probably use [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/), [LevelDB](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/), or (if your project is GPL-compatible), [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/).

Also, instead of malloc, you should probably consider the [slice allocator](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Slices.html).  You would still have long loads and saves (which you eliminate by using an embedded database), but it should be quite a bit faster than malloc.  Or, if you can use a 32-bit key instead of 64 you can just use [GINT_TO_POINTER](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html#GINT-TO-POINTER%3aCAPS) and speed things up even more.